# After several days of work: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, celery

I have the following system:

1. Each minute system creates several celery tasks
2. Each celery task opens Chrome browser (with help of Selenium library), opens web-page and analyze page data.
3. It's working fine but after several days I have an only error in logs `(Start_time=2022-09-30, first_error_time=2022-10-02)`

Errors appear when I open the browser (selenium object)
**How can I identify reason and fix the error?**

Error text:
Full error trace - https://pastebin.com/Yk7N0GEc

> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m [2022-10-02 14:15:04,239: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-16] Task parser_app.views.make_requests[13f3b9aa-fff7-46a6-a6fe-ac5a
> 19ca100b] raised unexpected: WebDriverException("unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exis
> t)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)", Non
> e, ['#0 0x55c360ee3403 ', '#1 0x55c360ce9778 ', '#2 0x55c360d0dfa9 ', '#3 0x55c360d0912b ', '#4 0x55c360d4483a ', '#5 0x55c360d3e8f3 ', '#6 0x55c360d140d8 ', '#7 0x55c360d15205 ', '#8 0x55c360f2ae3d ', '#9 0x55c360f2ddb6 ', '#10 0x55c360f1413e ', '#11 0x55c360f2e9b5 ', '#12 0x55c360f08970 ', '#13 0x55c360f4b228 ', '#14 0x55c360f
> 4b3bf ', '#15 0x55c360f65abe ', '#16 0x7f4ff204dea7 ', ''])
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m Traceback (most recent call last):
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
> ...
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/project/parser_app/parser/src.py", line 43, in **init**
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in **init**
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     super(WebDriver, self).**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in **init**
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     RemoteWebDriver.**init**(
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in **init**
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> ESC[36mcelery_1_522e9247a010 |ESC[0m   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

My thoughts:
What can be reason of the problem

1. Memory leak. (I don't think that it's possible, because celery automatically stops all tasks and I clear selenium resources)
2. Server is weak (I didn't think 16 CPU cores and 32 RAM)

Answer (score 1):

Using the

```
    --enable-logging=stdout
```

option, you should be able to see the logs for chromium itself.

Also, you might want to check if this problem happens in other languages, like python or java, as they will help narrow down the problem to a language-specific problem, or a problem with chromium.

You may also want to try downloading a new version of chromium. Maybe a new beta has fixed the issue, or maybe your version is corrupted.

Lastly, I would also try running this code on different operating systems.

If you're running on windows, maybe try macOS or Linux

If you're running on Linux or macOS, maybe give windows a shot.

Hope this helps